# Google Cloud SQL Instance Error IP Address

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am currently trying to Assign another IP Adress to my Google Cloud SQL Instance, in order to remotely connect to my database. However I keep getting the error "Your changes could not be saved".  I attempted to add the IP Adress from both the Edit option as well as the Access Control tab.

Comment: You can only assign a single IP address to an Cloud SQL instance.  Once you have an IP address you can authorize multiple IP addresses or subnets to access the instance remotely.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: No, I was simply attempting to add a subnet to access the instance remotely, not assign another IP address to the Cloud SQL instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big Thank You goes out to the Google Cloud team for helping us find our error. Someone on our team had put an improperly formatted IP address in the Authorized Network settings. This caused the instance settings to freeze up on us, which kept the instance from being edited within the Developer Console. By removing it, it solved our problem.